# Can A C Console App Run On Linux And Windows Both

Tags: c, windows, linux

If I Make A Program In C Without Including Windows.h Header File Will It Run On Linux.
I Am Making It In Code Blocks On Windows.

Comment: Also Can You Tell Me If i include Windows.h Will That Program Run On Windows 7 Or There Is Some Other Way To Make Windows 7 Programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they use completely different executable formats.  You will need to compile a separate executable for each platform.  If you stick to standard C it should compile for either though.

Comment: Good point, though not actually necessarily true in the presence of Wine

Answer (score 1):

If you only use the Standard C Library you'll be fine. if you go including `io.h` and `conio.h` and other junk like that, then you won't be fine.

Obviously I am assuming you are not expecting a windows PE to run on linux (without WINE) or a linux ELF to run on windows (you have to recompile like @sehe suggests).

Comment: And you need to recompile. I suggest compiling on linux, using winegcc or mingw32. On debian, these are trivial to install

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will unless you do some non-Linux specific (Windows or Mac) calls..which are unlikely, since you are not including `<windows.h>`.

Comment: Can You Also Suggest Me Any Tutorial On Socket Programming And Resource Other Than Winsock And Windows Resource Thing.. Thank You !!

Comment: That's a new question. You may want to ask it separately. Also, why are you Capitalising Every Word? It's difficult to read.

Comment: @Dapu: `man socket` is a good starting point and points at **[the sample client and server C programs in `man getaddrinfo`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)**; this will work on windows as well, normally, as it uses POSIX stuff only

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, it won't "run" on both Windows and Linux, but so long as you stick to the standard library, it'll compile on just about any platform.